# Unable to pass pig tuple to python UDF

Tags: python, hadoop, tuples, apache-pig, udf

I have master.txt which has 10K records, so each line of it will be a tuple & whole of the same needs to be passed to python UDF. Since it has multiple records, so on storing p2preportmap getting following error. Please help

Error is as follows:

> Unable to open iterator for alias p2preportmap. Backend error :
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar
>   has more than one row in the output. 1st : (010301,MTS,MM), 2nd
>   :(010B06,MTS,TN) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE
>   foo.bar" should be "foo::bar" )

Pig Script is as follows:

```
REGISTER 'smsiuc_udf.py' using streaming_python as smsiuc_udfs;
cdrs = load '2016040111*' USING PigStorage('|','-tagFile') ;

mastergtrec = load 'master.txt' USING PigStorage(',','-tagFile');

mastergt = FOREACH mastergtrec GENERATE (chararray) UPPER($1) as opcdpc, (chararray) UPPER($2) as gtoptname,(chararray) UPPER($3) as gtoptcircle;

mastergttup = FOREACH mastergt generate TOTUPLE(opcdpc,gtoptname,gtoptcircle) as mstgttup;

cdrrecord = FOREACH cdrs GENERATE (chararray) UPPER($1) as aparty, (chararray) UPPER($2) as bparty,$3 as smssentdate,$4 as smssenttime,($29=='6' ? 'S' : 'F') as status,(chararray) UPPER($26) as srcgt,(chararray) UPPER($27) as destgt,($12=='405899136999995' ? 'MTSDEL-CDMA' : ($12=='919875089998' ? 'MTSRAJ-GSM' : ($12=='405899150999995' ? 'MTSCHN-CDMA' : $12) ) ) as smscgt, (chararray)$0 as cdrfname,(chararray) $13 as prepost;

filteredp2pcdrs = FILTER cdrrecord by smsiuc_udfs.pullp2pcdrs(aparty,bparty,srcgt,destgt) and status == 'S' and SUBSTRING(smssentdate,4,6) == '$MON';

groupp2pcdrs = GROUP filteredp2pcdrs by (srcgt,destgt,aparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);

distinctp2pcdrs= FOREACH groupp2pcdrs {
uniq = DISTINCT filteredp2pcdrs.(srcgt,destgt,aparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);
GENERATE FLATTEN(group),COUNT(uniq) as cnt;
};

p2preportmap = FOREACH distinctp2pcdrs GENERATE smsiuc_udfs.p2preport(srcgt,destgt,aparty,bparty,mastergttup ),smscgt,status,prepost,cnt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding a dummy column and then grouping.

dummmy= foreach p2preportmap generate 1, $0,$1 ....

grouped = group dummy by $0

Comment: problem here is you have multiple records in your relation p2preportmap  you should combine them into one this can be done by above command or simpler one is grouped = group p2preportmap  by 1; now you can pass grouped into the udf

Comment: So u mean to say that i shud do group on mastergt like dummy= foreach mastergtrec generate 1,opcdpc,gtoptname,gtoptcircle & then grouped = group dummy by opcdpc.

Comment: no group dummy by $0  so that you get a single row.

Comment: but this gives error of Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (ALFA), 2nd :(AMIT) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar" should be "foo::bar). Can you please suggest

Comment: can you dump dummy and see if it has a single row. if you group by one then it should have a single row.

Comment: Got it.Now it is working.`p2preportmap = FOREACH distinctp2pcdrs GENERATE smsiuc_udfs.p2preport(srcgt,destgt,aparty,bparty,mastergttup.group),smscgt,status,prepost,cnt`. But now problem is on using the same in python udf i am unable to map the same in proper manner. Python udf is ` for counter,value in enumerate(mastergt): splitline= value.strip().split(",") optnamecircle[splitline[0]]=",".join(splitline[1:]) mastergtcircle[splitline[0]]=",".join(splitline[2:])`

Comment: Output without mapping is coming with first 3 chars missing in srcgt. `((CC_SELFCARE1,919810051023,,155,),MTSRAJ-GSM,S,postpaid,3)
((CC_SELFCARE1,919810051025,,155,),MTSRAJ-GSM,S,postpaid,2)
((CC_SELFCARE1,919825691400,,155,),MTSRAJ-GSM,S,postpaid,35)
((CC_SELFCARE1,919825691400,,155,),MTSRAJ-GSM,S,postpaid,1)`. Rest is fine otherwise, i am sure i am not iterating the same properly.

Comment: So you are loosing some characters of srcgt inside python udf?

Comment: yes and mapping is also not done. can you please advice on this.

Comment: I am not getting you can you explain what you are looking and where you are stuck

Comment: I have a file in which contents are like `010301,MTS,MM
010B06,MTS,TN
011407,MTS,MH
027406,MTS,AP
027807,MTS,AP
027900,MTS,AP
027A05,MTS,AS
027D01,MTS,BH
028103,MTS,MP
028800,MTS,GJ` which is grouped(mastergttup.group) and den passed to the function as suggested by you. On passing the same using `p2preportmap = FOREACH distinctp2pcdrs GENERATE smsiuc_udfs.p2preport(srcgt,destgt,aparty,bparty,mastergttup.group),smscgt,statu‌​s,prepost,cnt` getting d correct values in udf, but unable to map the 1st column of mastergttup wid d srcgt in python udf, I am iterating using d above code

Comment: mastergttup.group will be 1 you should pass the entire row that is mastergttup then access $1

Comment: Yes, my understanding was also on that lines, but it gives `A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar`. So passed it like this.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you a example I have two relation A and B

A

```
1,2,3
3,4,5
4,5,6
```

B

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Now i want a python udf that would lookup the first column of the A print output something like this below.

```
    ((1,{(1,2,3)}))
((2,))
((3,{(3,4,5)}))
((1,{(1,2,3)}))
((2,))
((3,{(3,4,5)}))
((1,{(1,2,3)}))
((2,))
((3,{(3,4,5)}))
```

So first i group A by first column and then group it by 1 so that i have single row

```
c = group A by $0
e = group c by 1
```

python udf is something like below

```
def pythonudf(value,map):
    print map
    temp = None
    for a in map:
        if a[0] == value:
            temp = a[1]
    return value,temp
```

now you use this udf

```
D = foreach B generate myudf.pythonudf($0,e.$1);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful explanation, i have been trying to do the same but still it is not working. when i dump group e i get this `1       {(master_gt_spc.txt,{(master.txt,9145,MTS,UPW),(master.txt,919225,MTS,WB),(master.txt,0101A0,MTS,TN),(master_gt_spc.txt,03F0,MTS,KL),(master.txt,YK,MTSI,KO),,(master_gt_spc.txt,YD-INDRLY,MTS,DL)})}`. When i print `a[0]` it gives `master.txt`, `a[1]` doesnt print in the UDF, `a[2]` also doesnt print. Python udf is `def map(srcgt,mastergttup): for tuplevalue in mastergttup: if tuplevalue[0] == srcgt:
return tuplevalue[1]`.

Comment: Output is not getting mapped as required.

Comment: looks like something is wrong with your relation e why is it having master_gt_spc.txt and master.txt  it should be srcgt values right? can you print c before grouping something went wrong while grouping.

Comment: yes, it is actually `1 {(master.txt,{(master.txt,9145,MTS,UPW),(master.txt,919225,MTS,WB),(maste‌​r.txt,0101A0,MTS,TN),(master_gt_spc.txt,03F0,MTS,KL),(master.txt,YK,MTSI,KO),(ma‌​ster_gt_spc.txt,YD-INDRLY,MTS,DL)})}` and print c is `master.txt {(master.txt,{(master.txt,9145,MTS,UPW),(master.txt,919225,MTS,WB),(maste‌​r.txt,0101A0,MTS,TN),(master_gt_spc.txt,03F0,MTS,KL),(master.txt,YK,MTSI,KO),(ma‌​ster_gt_spc.txt,YD-INDRLY,MTS,DL)})}`. I think we should group all and den ???

Comment: can you print A looks like the way you are getting c is wrong

Comment: I think we should group all and den can c `all {(9145,MTS,UPW),(919225,MTS,WB),(0101A0,MTS,TN),(03F0,MTS,KL),(YK,MTSI,KO),(YD-INDRLY,MTS,DL)})}`, but dis also is not working

Comment: Lets say you want a map to be passed to python udf you create a groupby column and then group by 1 and then pass it to python udf. Now if you want multiple  maps then you create multiple maps and group each by one and pass them to udf something like pythonudf(row,map1,map2...) i thing you were trying to merge all map to a single map.

Comment: If you provide with sample data I can give a try.

Comment: sent on your gmail id.

Comment: Vikas did u by any chance cracked the issue??

Comment: I sent a reply to your email. i was able to group and run the test i also sent you a sample of output

Comment: In case you can help on more issue posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315344/pig-pivoting-sum-3-relations. Will be obliged